# Pass dynamic checkbox text to next activity (android)

Tags: android

I am attempting to pass dynamic checkbox text to the next activity. I want to loop through the checkboxes by ID and see if they are checked. If they are, I want to take the text from the checkbox and concatenate it onto a string. When I run this, the app crashes. I know this is because of the intent. This is a quick, simple fix for a school deadline - any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: made some changes to addtocart() method, still not working.

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity {
public int count;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String results = intent.getStringExtra("key");
        if (results.equals("No results")) {
            //do nothing
        } else {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(results.split("-")));
            count = list.size() / 3;
            //puthere.setText(list.get(0));

            LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_ll);

            int isbn = 1;
            int title = 0;
            int price = 2;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
                checkBox.setText("Title: " + list.get(isbn) + ", ISBN: " + list.get(title) + ", Price: " + list.get(price));
                checkBox.setId(i);
                checkBox.setLayoutParams(params);
                linear.addView(checkBox);
                isbn = isbn + 3;
                title = title + 3;
                price = price + 3;
            }
        }
    }

    public void addtocart(View v) {
        String checked = "";

        ViewGroup viewgroup=(ViewGroup) v.getParent();
        int count = viewgroup.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Object child = viewgroup.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof CheckBox) {
                CheckBox checkboxchild = (CheckBox) child;
                if(checkboxchild.isChecked()) {
                    String text = checkboxchild.getText().toString();
                    checked = checked+"-"+text;
                }
            }

            Intent intent_name = new Intent(this, CheckOutActivity.class);
            intent_name.putExtra("somethingnew", checked);
            this.startActivity(intent_name);
        }
    }

    public void test(View v) {

    }
}
```

Comment: please attach the crash log to question.

Comment: all it says is "server connection has stopped", no errors logged in the logcat

Comment: if it says server, then focus on communication code (http requests)? permissions, server URL ? post the code related to the http request.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should read up first on how view ids work on Android. You cannot loop through incremental viewIds in a for loop; it doesn't work that way.

One possible way to loop is to do this:

```
ViewGroup viewgroup=(ViewGroup) view.getParent(); 
int count = viewgroup.getchildcount();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (viewGroup.getChildAt(i) instanceOf Checkbox) {
       if (((Checkbox) viewGroup.getChildAt(i)).isChecked()) {
         ...
       }
    }
}
```

Would highly recommend you to read the documentation on how Views work in Android first though.

Comment: k thanks! I really am just looking for a quick answer to get as far as I can on this, otherwise I would do some more studying tonight.

Comment: Anoop, can u please explain how your code is different from OP's code? also OP loops over `index` not `ID` !

Comment: yes, true, i checked first revision of question, it contained code deals with view ID.